# Razor - how to get n number characters of string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application with the following

**Model**

```
public string Price {get;set;}
```

it saves in database a string, eg. "41.99".

**View**

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <div class="price">@item.Price</div>
}
```

it returns the value "41.99" all good here.

however I would like to pick the values differently.

**Below is the Html output for what I need**

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <div class="price">
    <span class="dollar">41</span>
    <span class="cents">99</span>
</div>
}
```

- Please Note that the value is split in 2 parts and the dot is left out.
- The string will be inserted on input field as money, so it need to be inserted as **"41.99"**
- Other consideration is if the value before the dot are 1, 11, 111, 1111 characters, it need display all numbers.

So how could I archive this?

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <div class="price">
     <span class="dollar">@item.Price(first part)</span>
     <span class="cents">@item.Price(second part)</span>
 </div>
}
```

Any help or guindance would be apprecciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is string then

```
var price = "41.99";
var parts = price.Split('.');
var dollar = parts[0];
var cents = parts[1];
```

If your data is decimal

```
decimal price = 41.99m;
var dollar = (int)price;
var cents = (int)((price % 1) * 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the fact you should not be using string to represent numerical values and use `decimal` instead for money values... and the fact that `.` is not the only separator (depending on locale)...

`String.Split` is the easiest way to split the string on a separator:

```
var parts = item.Price.Split(`.`);
```

Now you have `parts[0]` with "dollar" value, and need to deal with fractional part which may or may not be there. Note that you may need to pad `cents` value if you need something like `04` instead of just `4`

```
  @{ 
     var parts = @item.Price.Split('.');
     var cents = (parts.Length == 2) ? cents = parts[1] : "0";
  }
  <span class="dollar">@parts[0]</span>
  <span class="cents">@cents</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all replies

I figured it out combining the answers here with some suggestions.

here is the answer for my question:
Model:

```
public double Price { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
var data = _Context.Products.Where(d => d.ProductId == id).First();

if (data == null)
{
return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(data);
}
```

In View:

```
string s = Model.Price.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string[] parts = s.Split('.');
int i1 = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int i2 = int.Parse(parts[1]);

<span>@i1</span>
<span class="decimal">@i2</span>
```

Works like a charm

Thanks a lot